# Launch Vehicle LM2D

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, china, hllv

As it is well known, the circularization of orbits needs at least 3 stages.

How could the Chinese launch vehicle LM2D circularizes its orbit with only 2 stages?

Comment: I would recommend you add some information about those three stages. Not everyone defines stages the same ways. Do you mean burn, coast burn? for example? Also, why do you say that "LM2D circularizes its orbit with only 2 stages?" Where does that come from? Can you add a link to a video or a website where this comes from? Thanks, and Welcome to Space!

Comment: Why would the circularization need "at least" 3 stages? It depends on the rocket and payload used.

Comment: "As it is well known, the circularization of orbits needs at least 3 stages", um, no. It can be done with one stage. You need more than one burn instead.

Comment: @Hobbes I wonder if it just a case of the wrong word; maybe it means three steps or three phases. Google wouldn't know that it was for a question in SpaceSE and avoid "stage" because of its other meaning perhaps?

Comment: @Hobbes You don’t even need more than one burn.